# "Error: matrix is not rectangular"... is this an error in *displaying* the data, or in creating/using the matrix?

Tags: arrays, matrix, google-apps-script

I am using Google Apps Script to work with a spreadsheet. My code isn't working, so I'm working on getting out the bugs. It's *supposed* to copy the spreadsheet values into an array, make some changes in the array, and then use those changes to re-write some parts of the spreadsheet and re-format other parts.

As part of my bug-checking, I tried writing the array back to a cell in the spreadsheet after all the desired changes are made. When I do, I get the error in the question title:

```
error: Matrix is not rectangular {" ","Score","Max Poss.","","","","asdf","","","","","","","";"Steve:",1,133,"","","","eFEf","","","","","","","";"Chris:",0,126,"","","","First we test the color change.","","","","","","","";"Tyler:",5,130,"","","","And now let's see...","","","","","","","";"Billy:",3,127,"","","","df","","","","","","","";"Drew:",0,122,"","","#N/A","gtttt","","","","","","","";"Yllib:",9,133,"","","","vrrr","","","","","","","";"","","","","","","","","","","","","","";"-W/L-","Drew","Steve","Chris","Tyler","Billy","HOME","AWAY","Billy","Tyler","Chris","Steve","Drew","-W/L-";"l",4,"",4,6,"","","",3,"","",1,"","w";"W","","","",5,"","","",9,"",6,3,5,"l";"",3,12,2,2,2,"","","","","","",""," ";"","","","","","","","",11,1,5,8,6," ";"",10,15,15,8,13,"","","","","","",""," ";"",8,10,14,16,12,"","","","","","",""," ";"","","","","","","","",10,14,10,16,14," ";"",13,13,11,13,16,"","","","","","",""," ";"","","","",4,"","","",4,"",9,6,16," ";"","",9,"","","","","",1,3,8,"",9," ";"","","","","","","","",8,12,13,2,12," ";"","","",1,"",5,"","","",11,"",4,1," ";"","","","","","","","",15,10,12,14,11," ";"",2,"",3,"",6,"","","",9,"",5,"","     ";"W";"",2,"",7,7,7,"NYG -2.5","","","","",7,""," "}
```

I've tried creating the array both using
    var sheetArray = new Array (30);
and
    var sheetArray = [];
with the same results.

I haven't turned up much on Google. I guess my big question is whether I am getting this error because I'm trying to display a rectangular array in a spreadsheet cell that isn't compatible, or if the problem is with the creation of the array itself or some other aspect unrelated to display.

Comment: when you say *"I tried writing the array back to a cell"* do you mean 1 cell or a range of cells ?

Comment: @Serge insas-- 1 cell. I assumed it would ask me to press ctrl+e to auto-expand, as it usually does when I write an array to a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are testing by writing an embedded array in a spreadsheet formula:

`={"a","b","c";"d","e","f"}`

You are getting the error message because your matrix is not rectangular. :-)

The offending row is the second last row, where you have one element "W" in that row:

`..."     ";"W";"",2,"",7,7,7,"NYG -2.5","","","","",7,""," "}`

So I guess there is an error somewhere in your construction of the array (if you needed help with that, feel free to post some code into the question).

Comment: Thanks! You have functionally answered my question... later on the script iterates through the array, and having no value instead of "" must be making it break.

I should have figured that out myself, but I was too focused on the less important question (in terms of my script actually working.) However, I'm still curious why I should otherwise care that my array is not rectangular. My script still runs start to finish (it just doesn't do what it's supposed to do), and the error only exists as a comment in a cell. So... suppose I didn't iterate through the blank values, is this a problem?

Comment: By the way, just for your info-- no, I was testing to make sure the array is being created properly, so I took the array created by the script and wrote it to a cell. And to further clarify my last question: is the fact that the array even exists as a non-rectangular array a problem in and of itself? Or is it just a problem when trying to display it in a spreadsheet, or in some specific aspects of trying to work with it?